# Got 500 Error in RECORD Protocol in RTSP Handshake (Airtunes in Android)

Tags: java, android, rtsp, airplay

I'm trying to make communications between Android and Airplay Device.
Announce / Setup Protocol is OK. But I've got 500 Error in RTSP Record Handshake.

I took a reference in Airtunes with NODE.js (https://npmjs.org/package/airtunes)

Logcat Attached

```
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): Try request
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): CSeq: 1
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): User-Agent: BugsOnAir/1.4.0
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): AppleWebKit/536.30.1
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): Client-Instance: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): DACP-ID: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): Active-Remote: 290802668
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): Apple-Challenge: 09KF45soMYmvj6dpsUGiIg
09-09 16:46:25.066: D/REQUEST(8591): 
09-09 16:46:25.081: D/RESPONSE(8591): TYPE:OPTIONS
09-09 16:46:25.081: D/RESPONSE(8591): DESC: {public= ANNOUNCE, SETUP, RECORD, PAUSE, FLUSH, TEARDOWN, OPTIONS, GET_PARAMETER, SET_PARAMETER, POST, GET, cseq= 1, server= AirTunes/141.9}
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Try request
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): ANNOUNCE rtsp://10.22.145.12/32768767 RTSP/1.0
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): CSeq: 2
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): User-Agent: BugsOnAir/1.4.0
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): AppleWebKit/536.30.1
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Client-Instance: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): DACP-ID: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Active-Remote: 290802668
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Apple-Challenge: 09KF45soMYmvj6dpsUGiIg
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Content-Type: application/sdp
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): Content-Length: 568
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): 
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): v=0
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): o=iTunes 32768767 0 In IP4 10.22.145.12
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): s=iTunes
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): c=In IP4 10.22.145.12
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): t=0 0
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): a=rtpmap:96 AppleLossless
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): a=fmtp:96 352 0 16 40 10 14 2 255 0 0 44100
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): a=rsaaeskey:VjVbxWcmYgbBbhwBNlCh3K0CMNtWoB844BuiHGUJT51zQS7SDpMnlbBIobsKbfEJ3SCgWHRXjYWf7VQWRYtEcfx7ejA8xDIk5PSBYTvXP5dU2QoGrSBv0leDS6uxlEWuxBq3lIxCxpWO2YswHYKJBt06Uz9P2Fq2hDUwl3qOQ8oXb0OateTKtfXEwHJMprkhsJsGDrIc5W5NJFMAo6zCiM9bGSDeH2nvTlyW6bfI/Q0v0cDGUNeY3ut6fsoafRkfpCwYId+bg3diJh+uzw5htHDyZ2sN+BFYHzEfo8iv4KDxzeya9llqg6fRNQ8d5YjpvTnoeEQ9ye9ivjkBjcAfVw
09-09 16:46:25.091: D/REQUEST(8591): a=aesiv:ePRBLI0XN5ArFaaz7ncNZw
09-09 16:46:25.106: D/RESPONSE(8591): TYPE:ANNOUNCE
09-09 16:46:25.106: D/RESPONSE(8591): DESC: {cseq= 2, server= AirTunes/141.9}
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): Try request
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): SETUP rtsp://10.22.145.12/32768767 RTSP/1.0
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): CSeq: 3
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): User-Agent: BugsOnAir/1.4.0
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): AppleWebKit/536.30.1
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): Client-Instance: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): DACP-ID: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): Active-Remote: 290802668
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;mode=record;control_port=6000;timing_port=6001
09-09 16:46:25.111: D/REQUEST(8591): 
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/RESPONSE(8591): TYPE:SETUP
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/RESPONSE(8591): DESC: {audio-jack-status= connected; type=analog, server= AirTunes/141.9, cseq= 3, session= 1, transport= RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;mode=record;server_port=1345;control_port=1347;timing_port=1349}
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): Try request
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): RECORD rtsp://10.22.145.12/32768767 RTSP/1.0
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): CSeq: 4
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): Session: 1
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): User-Agent: BugsOnAir/1.4.0
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): AppleWebKit/536.30.1
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): Client-Instance: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): DACP-ID: 3eb953b
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): Active-Remote: 290802668
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): Range: npt=0-
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): RTP-Info: seq=7469;rtptime=44900426
09-09 16:46:25.241: D/REQUEST(8591): 
09-09 16:46:58.666: E/RESPONSE(8591): GOT ERROR: 500
```

Comment: Can you specify what the Airplay device is? Apple TV?

Comment: Are you responding to the time sync packets that get sent by the device after SETUP?